# Problem with mixing Latin and Arabic text in QTextEdit

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qtextedit

I'm using QTextEdit to show messages in my app. My problem is that QTextEdit doesn't show messages correctly when I use Latin and Arabic text simultaneously.

Correct order:

[image]

Incorrect order:

[image]

As you can see, the QTextEdit doesn't show message in correct order.

I've tried to solve the problem using CSS style, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't see your code so I can't help

Comment: Most of us cannot read Arabic, so we cannot have a valid context to understand the difference between those images. With proper context, though, we may still be able to help: how was that text added? Is it completely created by code? Do you insert part of it while other text already exists? And which one? Or is this an insertion from the clipboard? From what source? Please take your time to [edit] your question and provide more details, possibly including a valid [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I've solved the problem by the following code:

`text_option = QTextOption(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)` `text_option.setTextDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.RightToLeft)` `self.conversationsTextEdit.document().setDefaultTextOption(text_option)`